# Persistent Passport logins for Google and Local

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I implemented a local and Google strategy for my MEAN stack application using Passport. I am able to login locally. I can also get a token from Google on the client side. I want to be able to persist the login, if the user is using a trusted device. 
When I close the browser; however, the user has to log in again or the node server refuses the connection. The authorization code looks like this:

```
 function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
       return next();
    }
 }
```

What is the best way to persist the authorization for local and google strategies? I was thinking of creating a token for local strategy and then set the headers to pass the token in Angular and authorize by looking up the token in Node. Does this approach make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a token is a good idea, but it doesn't yet make the authentication to persist. Use eg. [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to persist the token in the browser. localStorage is persistent way to store information on the client side.

There are few popular ways to make a token based authentication. One that works pretty much like you described is [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) (link for Node.js).